# How to record page numbers html-pdf node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I'm using html-pdf for node.js to create a pdf from html. Built into html-pdf is the ability to add page numbers to the footers. I want to record those page numbers somehow, maybe in an array. This is my current code:

```
let index = 0;
let myIndex = [];

<div id="pageHeader" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 30px;"></div>
                <body class='page'>      
                    ${myHtmlText} 
                </body>
<div id="pageFooter" style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">{{page}}</div>
```

{{page}} within the pageFooter div automatically increases the page number by 1 each new page. How do I record the value of the page numbers in a variable?

Answer (score 3):

```
let options = {
            height: '11.25in',
            width: '8.5in',
            header: {
              height: '5mm',
            },
            footer: {
              height: '10mm',
              contents: {
                default:
                  '<div id="pageFooter" style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">{{page}}/{{pages}}</div>',
              },
            },
          };
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf